# How can I get one object to stick to another after they contact?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, 2d-games

New to swift and coding in general so forgive me if there is any easy way to do this.

I'm trying to make a simple game in which arrows hit a shield.  When the arrows contact the shield I would like them to sort of "stick" into the shield. The shield also moves around so I assume I would need some sort of anchor attaching the sprites.  What type of anchor should I use for this, and how should I go about starting?

I tried something like:

```
        let arrowJoint = SKPhysicsJointFixed.jointWithBodyA(firstBody, bodyB: secondBody, anchor: contact.contactPoint)
        self.physicsWorld.addJoint(arrowJoint)
```

In which firstBody is the physics group of the shield, and secondBody the arrow.  No luck though.  They don't stick and then the game crashes.

Comment: If I were doing it,  I would make the arrows become a child of the shield node

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on that?

Comment: Something like shield.addChildNode(arrowBody). Just may have do some math to translate it from screen coordinates to shield coordinates